# Wait for download until previous file is downloaded

Tags: vb.net, loops, asynchronous, download, webclient

I have got a `DataTable` which contains information for files. I iterate through this table and a state controls what happens with this files (delete, add new, update). In the case of add new and update the single file has to be download from a server and save in the file system. This works fine without any problems.

Now there is a new request. Currently the user get only at the end a note that the file download is finished. Now the user wants to get during the download process this hint how much is downloaded. How could I implement this? It is necessary that a new file download starts when the previous download is finished.

My current code looks like:

```
Dim oDownloadFileClient As New System.Net.WebClient

For Each Row As DataRow In fileTable.Rows
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Start processing file {0}", Row("FileName").Value))

    Select Case Row("State").Value
        Case 0
            'delete file
        Case 1 'new file
            Try
                'download file
                Dim oFile As Byte() = oDownloadFileClient.DownloadData("<DownloadPath>")
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(FileName, oFile)

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("File {0} saved.", Row("FileName").Value))
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Case 2, 3 'update file
            Try
                Dim oFile As Byte() = oDownloadFileClient.DownloadData("<DownloadPath>")
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(FileName, oFile)

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("File {0} updated.", Row("FileName").Value))
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Case Else
    End Select
Next
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edited Code**

```
Dim oDownloadFileClient As New System.Net.WebClient
AddHandler oDownloadFileClient.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf DownloadProgressCallback

For Each Row As DataRow In fileTable.Rows
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Start processing file {0}", Row("FileName").Value))

    Select Case Row("State").Value
        Case 0
            'delete file
        Case 1 'new file
            Try
                'download file
                oDownloadFileClient.DownloadFileAsync("<DownloadPath>", FileName)

                While (oDownloadFileClient.IsBusy)

                End While

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("File {0} saved.", Row("FileName").Value))
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Case 2, 3 'update file
            Try
                oDownloadFileClient.DownloadFileAsync("<DownloadPath>", FileName)

                While (oDownloadFileClient.IsBusy)

                End While

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("File {0} updated.", Row("FileName").Value))
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Case Else
    End Select
Next
```

```
Private Sub DownloadProgressCallback(sender As Object, e As Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}% downloaded"), e.ProgressPercentage)
End Sub
```

Comment: Saving it as a `Byte` array and then writing it to a file is useless. Just do `oDownloadFileClient.DownloadFileAsync("<DownloadPath>", FileName)`, _[reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)_. --- As for your problem, you could get use of the [DownloadProgressChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event and the properties in it's [event args](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadprogresschangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If I try this the program doesn't wait until the file is downloaded (because it's async). After this command I add a while-loop with check of `oDownloadFileClient.IsBusy` thereby the file is downloaded before the next file will be downloaded. Now I have got the problem that in the command line first is shown that the file is saved (for every file in the list) and after this the outputs from the `DownloadProgressChanged` event are shown. How can I fix this that first comes the text that the download is startet, than the percentages from the event and at the end that it is finished?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to do it asynchronously, then change it to `DownloadFile(...`. **But if you do that** you will freeze the main UI, which will result in **not displaying** the download progress. "`and at the end that it is finished?`" - You could do a little research on the [WebClient's events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_events(v=vs.110).aspx). _Hint: Each of the download methods has it's own event. Make sure you pick the right one. :)_

Comment: Now it works asynchronously. It was a fault in my approach of the implementation. I reorganised my source code and now one file is downloaded and after this the next file will start. The Progress is also displayed. Thanks for the hints :D